# element.style.backgroundColor not working on WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have been trying to get the background of a button to change upon hover. I already have the code but it does work but for some reason. When I place it in WordPress, the background does not change.

Here is the working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/TopoX84/3oqgmjb0/

Here is the WordPresswebsite:
http://visionhostingsolutions.pro/

I also added to jQuery the `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But, it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your website, but it boils down to the fact you're using `!important` for several of your CSS styles. These prevent the JavaScript from modifying the `color` and `background-color` of the button.

Your CSS on the website (which is different to what you've shown in your JsFiddle) is:

```css
<style>
#buttonmodcss {
  display: inline !important;
  text-align: center !important; 
  width: 105px !important;
  height: 35px !important;
  border: 1px solid #5472d2 !important;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  background: #ffffff !important; // Causes the problem
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
  color: #5472d2 !important; // Causes the problem
}
</style>
```

There's also a reference in `style.css` which will cause problems with your button:

```css
<style>
button:hover,
a.button:hover,
a.button:visited:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: transparent !important; // Causes a problem
}
</style>
```

Unless there are some elements of the site that are completely out of your control, you should *very rarely* need to use `!important` in your CSS. If you can, avoid using `!important` completely and focus on using [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) instead of override styles when required.

#### Other Issues

There are a few other issues to take into account:

1. You don't need to include jQuery with WordPress; it does it automatically. Your site is currently including jQuery twice:

```html
    <!-- line 17 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- line 175 -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://visionhostingsolutions.pro/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

2. Your JavaScript functions do not use jQuery at all, so the inclusion of jQuery is irrelevant in this case.
3. This should be done using CSS on `#buttonmodcss:hover` rather than using JavaScript for this effect.

#### Use CSS instead of JavaScript

I can't see any obvious reasons why you've chosen to use JavaScript instead of CSS, but using CSS would be easier for what you're trying to achieve:

```css
<style>
    #buttonmodcss {
      display: inline;
      text-align: center; 
      width: 105px;
      height: 35px;
      border: 1px solid #5472d2;
      margin-top: 0px !important;
      background: #ffffff; // No !important
      border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
      color: #5472d2; // No !important
    }
    #buttonmodcss:hover {
        color: "#fff";
        background: "#5472d2";
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thank you for the great feedback, I'm started to use wordPress not too long ago, there are many thing that still unknown and im learning as i go.

Comment: Phill Healey answer got the issue resolved, but you also covered multiple issue placed on my website, providing great understand on the overall of css, greatly appreciated and i have noted it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some JavaScript that is changing the inline style of the button. This overrides any other inline style that you apply since the JS is effectively changing the markup.

To override this you would ideally need to change the JS itself or even remove the script that is affecting this button.

However, as a last resort you could use this css:

```
input#buttonmodcss:hover {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

I've used black here for demo purposes but you could of course change this to your desired colour.

P.s. WordPress already loads JQuery so you shouldn't load it again. Also, when you do load scripts you should enqueue them and NOT add them directly to the head. This is very bad practise.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the feedback specially on the bad practices, i'll keep an eye on them